# JavaScript: Update a value that is the sum of two range values

Tags: javascript

I recently started to work on Django and JavaScript, and currently working on Range items. I successfully managed to have two functioning scales and to update their value next to them each time the user is modifying them.

```
<p>You are spending<span id="demo1"></span> dollars on this item.</p>
<div class="input-group">
    <p class="input-group-text">0<input type="range" id="myRange1" name="myRange" min="0" max = "120" step="5" class="form-range"></p>
    <p class="input-group-text"> 120</p>
</div>

var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
output1.innerHTML = slider1.value; 
slider1.oninput = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}

<p>You are spending<span id="demo2"></span> dollars on this item.</p>
    <div class="input-group">
        <p class="input-group-text">0<input type="range" id="myRange2" name="myRange" min="0" max = "120" step="5" class="form-range"></p>
        <p class="input-group-text"> 120</p>
    </div>

    var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
    var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
    output2.innerHTML = slider2.value; 
    slider2.oninput = function() {
      output2.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
```

Now, what I am trying to get is to have a value that is the sum of the two values, and that is updating as soon as the user is modifying one of the two scales. I tried the following:

```
<p>You have spent <span id="demo_total"></span> dollars in total.</p>

var value_total = 0
var output_total = document.getElementById("demo_total");
output_total.innerHTML = 120 // Display the default slider value
value_total.value = function() {
  output_total.innerHTML = parseInt(output1.innerHTML) + parseInt(output2.innerHTML);
}
```

But without success. Could you help me to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why did you put `output_total.innerHTML = parseInt(output1.innerHTML) + parseInt(output2.innerHTML);` in a function? Remove the function around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the code I see that you are not adding your listeners correctly, you need to fix that first. After having listeners working correctly on each slider input event, you could be computing the total and assigning it to the innerHTML as you are doing it right now.

For the listeners check this: [W3Schools JS DOM listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried several of the input suggested on the website but I am a complete beginner in JavaScript. Could you hint me where in my code should I put the listener? Thank you.

Comment: You should put the listeners on the sliders `document.getElementById("sliderID").addEventListener("input", sliderInput);`. The logic is:
You put a listener to whenever a slider gets an input (in your scenario you have 2 sliders) and inside the function `sliderInput` you could read the value of each slider, make the addition and assign the value on to your other tag.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working as per your requirement.

```
<p>You are spending<span id="demo1"></span> dollars on this item.</p>
<div class="input-group">
    <p class="input-group-text">0<input type="range" id="myRange1" name="myRange" min="0" max = "120" step="5" class="form-range"></p>
    <p class="input-group-text"> 120</p>
</div>

<p>You are spending<span id="demo2"></span> dollars on this item.</p>
    <div class="input-group">
        <p class="input-group-text">0<input type="range" id="myRange2" name="myRange" min="0" max = "120" step="5" class="form-range"></p>
        <p class="input-group-text"> 120</p>
    </div>

    <p>You have spent <span id="demo_total"></span> dollars in total.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
    var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
    var output_total = document.getElementById("demo_total");
    var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
    var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");

    var value_total = 0
    output1.innerHTML = slider1.value; 
    slider1.oninput = function() {
      output1.innerHTML = this.value;
      output_total.innerHTML = +this.value + +output2.innerHTML //on update of slider 1
    }
    output2.innerHTML = slider2.value; 
    output_total.innerHTML = 120;
    slider2.oninput = function() {
      output2.innerHTML = this.value;
      output_total.innerHTML = +this.value + +output1.innerHTML //on update of slider 2
    }
</script>
```